Different execution for a task (test) when using IDE vs command line
I need to use Kotlin Gradle tests from command line and I've run into some issues.

when I run task via IDE (intelliJ) and pick a task like test everything works, when I change source code, this is reflected in output of the test run

> Task :checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileTestKotlin
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 857ms
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed


when in project directory I execute ./gradlew test --info I receive output ending with:

>
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
Skipping task ':testClasses' as it has no actions.
:testClasses (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
:test (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) started.

> Task :test UP-TO-DATE
file or directory '/Users/jarek/plugs/code-analyzer-idea/build/classes/java/test', not found
Caching disabled for task ':test' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Skipping task ':test' as it is up-to-date.
:test (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 369ms
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
Watched directory hierarchies: [/Users/jarek/plugs/code-analyzer-idea]

>

The output is always reflecting status of last test task run from within IDE, IDE and command line executions are somehow connected.
Output of these two executions differs though, looking at ending, it appears IDE task was running the tests, while command line execution skipped testing, as it reports that folder with classes is not found.
What could go wrong in this case? Why am I seeing different results here?

The test task can be up-to-date if neither the sources nor the build script have changed, thus doesn't need to be re-run

The issue is that sources have changed, but running it through gradlew, ignores those changes, unlike running it through IDE.

Which IDE are you using? Did you make sure to save the file to disk before running Gradle commands? Some IDEs like IntelliJ will auto-save files when a user action is performed such as build/test, or if you switch focus to the embedded terminal, but that might not happen if you go to an external terminal. Some other IDEs might not auto-save at all

Thank you, for assistance with this, I got stupid error, where project was set without autosaving which I normally use, I tried to save manually to check - but probably the save action didn't happen so I assumed there is some strange issue. (and assumed that when it is saved by Gradle executor dialog, switching to in IDE terminal will save it as well). Thanks again, next time I triple check :D
